# Apache and MySQL error in Xampp

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, xampp

I downloaded MySQL, php and Apache separate but I had to download Xampp. For this reason I am receiving this error when loading Xampp.

[image]

I tried to uninstall Apache using -k uninstall function but still it is giving me this error.

Comment: The error messages tell you what is wrong and what you need to change.

Comment: You installed a version of Apache before you found XAMPP. Its till there and because its self installed it is started automatically on boot. so its using port 80 and stopping the Apache installed by XAMPP from starting. Uninstall theat Other Apache, and MySQL as well

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try using e.g. `httpd.exe -k uninstall -n "Apache2.4"` rather than simply `httpd.exe -k uninstall`. Windows also has [sc delete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc742045(v=ws.11)), which can remove services ex. `sc delete Apache2.4`. You will need to stop Apache prior to deleting it with either `httpd.exe -k stop` or e.g. `httpd -k stop -n "Apache2.4"`.

You can also take similar steps with the MySQL service:

```
net stop MySQL
sc delete MySQL
```

*Notes*

- All of these commands should be run from an elevated (administrative) command prompt. To do this, open the `Run...` dialog from the Windows Start Menu, type `cmd` then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Alternately, you can select the `Run as administrator` option when right-clicking the `cmd.exe` result.
- The Windows Services menu can also stop both Apache and MySQL (assuming you do not wish to do so from the command line). Likewise, it can help you determine a service name if you are uncertain about what to use in the commands above.
- As a suggestion, you may also wish to consider reinstalling XAMPP after the separate services above have successfully been removed (though this seems unlikely to be necessary under normal circumstances).